# Can't seem to install PHP-FPM5?

Tags: centos, php, php-fpm, php5, centos6.5

I am reading some advice on the internet for a solution to another issue I have.  It requires me to change the `listen` to `/var/run/php5-fpm/php5-fpm.sock`.

I however don't have that folder.. I have a `php-fpm` folder but that's it. I have installed all php-fpm repositories I found, I have enabled the **remi repository**, and yet when I run the command:

```
sudo service php5-fpm status
```

I get this:

```
php5-fpm: unrecognized service.
```

**info.php** is telling me however that I have **PHP 5.5.12 FPM/FastCGI** installed.

I am a n00b to creating my own servers, I use google for everything. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Stop following random advice on the internet and read the official docs for the software you are trying to use so you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

## Php-fpm

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php
>
> http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/8/php5-fpm/

## Unix sockets

> http://www.thomasstover.com/uds.html
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919441/priciples-of-unix-domain-socket-how-does-it-works

---

## Troubleshooting services

```
# Find out what the service is ACTUALLY called before running it
ls /etc/init.d/ | grep "fpm"
ls /etc/init.d/ | grep "php"
rm -rf /
```

---

Read manuals and try to understand things before blindly following instructions online.